# Page flashes to anchor before scrolling from top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Someone please help me.

I have one page with several hidden sections on it and a series of other pages that link to and show these sections. Originally the page just jumped straight to the anchor but I made it to where the page scrolls from the top to the section instead; the problem is that the page briefly jumps to the anchor before jumping to the top of the page and then scrolling.

Here is my code:

```
function toggle(id) {
 var element = document.getElementById(id);
 var text = document.getElementById("arrow" + id);
   if (element) {
   var display = element.style.display;

   if (display == "none" || display == '') {
   element.style.display = "block";
  text.innerHTML = "&#9650;";

  } else {
   element.style.display = "none";
   text.innerHTML = "&#x25bc;";
       }
    }
 };

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(window.location.hash).show(); 

     if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('html, body').scrollTop(0,0).show();
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top
                -75}, 1000)
        }, 0);
   }
});
```

Here is one page:

```
<p><a href="http://204.128.208.7/automated-transfers-users/#inventoryPriceMaintenance">Effect on Auto-Transfers</a></p>
```

Here is part of the page it links to:

```
<h4 class="blueToggle" onclick="toggle('inventoryPriceMaintenance')">An Incorrect Setting in Inventory Price Maintenance<a id="arrowinventoryPriceMaintenance">&#x25bc;</a></h4>
<div id="inventoryPriceMaintenance" class="hiddencontent">
<p style="margin-left: 2em; margin-bottom: .3em;">Navigate to the back-screen</p>
<a href="http://204.128.208.7/wp-content/uploads/auto-transfer-7.png"><img class="aligncenter" src="http://204.128.208.7/wp-content/uploads/auto-transfer-7.png" alt="" width="85%" height="85%" /></a>
<p style="text-align: justify; margin-left: 2em; line-height: 1.5em; margin-bottom: .625em;">The item will not be included on automatically generated transfers to a store if the second character in the fourth column (<strong>COMP</strong>) is…</p>

<ul style="margin-left: 5em; line-height: 1.5em;">
<li><strong>D</strong> = discontinued (an item cannot be transferred to a store at which it is discontinued, but it can be transferred from that store)</li>
<li><strong>S</strong> = special order</li>
<li><strong>X</strong> = item has been discontinued everywhere (only relevant at store 00)</li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: justify; margin-left: 2em;">An item will not auto-transfer if it is not authorized at the specific store</p>
<p style="text-align: justify; margin-left: 5em; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: -1em; margin-bottom: 0px">Go to the back-screen and see if the store is on the list (a list of authorized stores can also be found on the Inventory Inquiry screen)</p>
<h4 class="blueToggle" onclick="toggle('inventoryPriceMaintenance')" style="margin-top: .3em">Hide -</h4>
</div>
```

I have looked for a solution, and tried e.preventDefault(); and return false, but neither have worked and I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: The browser will move to the anchor position before the JS has even loaded. I don't believe you can cancel that with JS, though you could work around it using a query string, or anchors that don't exist (Then the JS can work out what they relate to)

Comment: What is an anchor that doesn't exist?

Comment: E.g. on your page you have `#thisAnchor`, but you just link to `.com#this`, then the JS does something like `window.location.hash + "Anchor"` to get the real anchor. This way the browser wont move the page (`#this` doesn't exist) but your JS can still move to it as it knows to add the consistent final part.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comments, the browser will automatically move to any existing anchors. To get around this you can link to anchors that don't actually exist, but still carry enough information for your JS to know the element.

The easiest way to do this would be to use anchors with a consistent last part, "thisAnchor", "thatAnchor", "anyTextAnchor". (All have the post-fix "Anchor")

Then you can link to "#this" and use JS to add the post-fix "Anchor", giving you the valid element to use in your animation, while leaving the browser with an invalid element (and therefor initial position is set)

Step by step this would mean:

- An anchor element with the ID `thisAnchor`
- Link to `http://example.com#this`
- Your JS appends "Anchor" to create "thisAnchor", which can then be used

And in code, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // This is just for the example, as I can't add an anchor to a stack snippet 
  window.location.hash = 'this'; 
  //
  
  if (window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Here we add the common post-fix "Anchor" to any anchor link passed in
      var scrollTo = $(window.location.hash + "Anchor").offset().top;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
      }, 1000)
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 4000px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Use anchors with a common post-fix such as "Anchor" -->
  <a id="thisAnchor">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

Alternative with no ID changes, you can have a list of aliases for the anchor, e.g. `.com#a` goes to `#this`. Simple example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // This is just for the example, as I can't add an anchor to a stack snippet 
  window.location.hash = 'a'; 
  //
  
  if (window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var scrollTo = 0;
      // Lookup which element this # relates to
      switch(window.location.hash){
        case "#a":
          scrollTo = $("#this").offset().top;
          break;
        case "#b":
          scrollTo = $("#that").offset().top;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
      }, 1000)
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 4000px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}
a{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Any existing anchor -->
  <a id="this">This Anchor</a>
  <a id="that">That Anchor</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately this method won't work because adding the post-fix breaks my toggle functionality.

Comment: @Erin I can't really help with that without seeing this "toggle functionality", but you could potentially do something similar by having a list of known anchors and their associate elements, but that gets far messier in the JS. (`.com#a` goes to "#this", `.com#b` goes to `#that` etc) However that wouldn't require any change to the current IDs

Comment: I added the code that toggles the sections and the html code of both pages.

Comment: @Erin I've added a version which doesn't require you to change your IDs on the page (though still requires a different "link") does that solve the issue? I'm afraid that if you can't change either of the link or the ID, I can't think of any way to stop the initial positioning.

Comment: Initially I can't get the second method to work either, but I'm going to keep tinkering and see if I can make it work. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it immensely.